# Trigger after insert

Tags: sql-server, trigger, insert, copy

How would look syntax of Trigger creation for Copying Column1 from table 1 in to new table 2 after instert value into any of columns of Table 1 ?

Comment: Please try to clarify your question. Maybe adding an example?

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--Create Test tables
Create table dbo.Table1 (ID int, col1 varchar(10))
Create table dbo.Table2 (ID int, col1 varchar(10))

--Create AFTER insert trigger
create TRIGGER [dbo].[Table1_CopyColl1ToTable2] ON [dbo].[Table1]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

--insert the rows from the virtual inserted table into table2
insert into dbo.Table2(ID,col1)
    select ID,col1 from inserted
END

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] ENABLE TRIGGER [Table1_CopyColl1ToTable2]
GO

--Insert test rows into Table1
insert into dbo.Table1(ID,col1) values(1,'Test')

Select * from dbo.Table2
```

---

For more information about the virtual *inserted* and *deleted* [Use the inserted and deleted Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables).